# Cannot restore RecyclerView state after screen orientation change because saved state is null. Why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview with some data in a Fragment. If I change the screen orientation, I want to save the state and reload it upon screen orientation change.

Here is my Fragment class:

```
public class DataUsageFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "DataUsage";
private static final boolean debug = true;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
private DataUsageManager dataUsageManager;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public DataUsageFragment() {
}

public static DataUsageFragment getInstance(String title) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getInstance: called");
    DataUsageFragment fragment = new DataUsageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (debug) Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView is called");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_usage, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (debug) Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated is called");

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    Context context = view.getContext();
    dataUsageManager = new DataUsageManager(getActivity(), 0);

    // RecyclerView
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_data);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: savedInstanceState in onViewCreated IS NULL!");
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    } else {
        if (recyclerViewState == null)
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: AAAAAAAAA");
        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() == null)
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: BBBBBBBBB");
        recyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ListState");
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
    }

    // Data Usage
    // int spinnerItemPos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: NULLNULLNULL");
        // if current API Level < 23 (Marshmallow), use TrafficStats, else NetworkStatsManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            dataUsageManager.useTrafficStats();
        } else {
            dataUsageManager.useNetworkStatsManager();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: QQQQQQQQ");
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: called");
    recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable("ListState", recyclerViewState);
}
```

}

In onViewCreated(), I included some Log messages when checking on null.
It seems that both `recyclerViewState` and `recyclerView.getLayoutmanager()` are null because it prints "AAAAAAAAA" and "BBBBBBBBB". I don't understand why. I followed several SO questions and did the same thing, it should work.

Why are `recyclerViewState` and `recyclerView.getLayoutmanager()` both null?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `RecyclerView` does this automatically. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake
I want to keep the RecyclerView with all its data when I change screen orientation without fetching the data again (here: without calling again for example `dataUsageManager.useNetworkStatsManager()`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this similar problem in the future...

I solved it by adding the following to the Android manifests file:

```
<application
        <activity
            ...
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            ...
        </activity>
</application>
```

This seems to be sufficient when it comes to keeping the states of activities / fragments when dealing with configuration changes.